# Buttons clickable area

Tags: css

What css styles to be applied to make the clickable area of button to the exact shape of the button.Could you please tell me

Comment: Is it a web or windows app? And I thought the full area of a button is always clickable, unless you're styling a link to look like a button and have padding, margin and border set on it. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTML you have to use a somewhat obsolete technique - [Image maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.6) - to get a clickable area that's not in the shape of a square. If you use Flash, you have more options. This reply addresses HTML/XHTML up to version 4, I haven't read the the specs for HTML 5 wich may have more ways of solving this (probably in combination with Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If I wish to style links in a menu I use an unordered list. You need to use display:block to make the whole list item click-able. I have included example css and html below.

In my stylesheet:

```
#menu {
width: 800px;
height: 40px;
}

#menu ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#menu li {
display: inline;
margin-right: 10px;
float: left;
background-color: #FC0;
}

#menu a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #006;
display:block;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

#menu a:hover,
#menu a:active {
color: #009;
background-color: #F90;
}
```

In my html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will give you a horizontal menu of three yellow boxes/buttons which will change to orange on hover. The a is displayed as a block and so the hover affect takes affect when the mouse hovers anywhere within the yellow box, rather than just over the text.

Hope this helps :o)